# Simulating A4 printing result

Tags: imagemagick

I've been trying, without success, to simulate a printed version of an image in A4 dimensions.

My approach was:

1. Create a white A4 image:
   `convert -size 595x843^ xc:white a4.jpg`
2. Resize the original image:
   `convert original.jpg -resize 545x842 original_resize.jpg`
3. Mix them up:
   `composite original_resize.jpg a4.jpg final.jpg`

But the result is not really achieving my goal.

Example what I want to get (omit that the second picture is in grey-scale):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. But now it's quite clear this is not a programming question.

Comment: There are a lots of Imagemagick questions. Why mine is not accepted ? this is really frustrating

Comment: For an ImageMagick question to be on-topic here, it must be about programming. That probably means it's about the ImageMagick library, not the command-line tool.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want, you can do that in ImageMagick command line as:

Input:

[image]

```
convert logo.jpg -resize 595x843 -gravity center -background white -extent 595x843 logo_result.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

If that is not what you want, then please explain further.

Comment: Fantastic!. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!